# Finding Im$f$ when $Re(f) = x^3 - 3xy^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Let $f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x,y)$ and also $f$ is a holomporphic function, where $u(x, y) = x^3-3xy^2$ I want to find $v(x, y)$.

**My work so far**

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x } = 3x^2 - 3y^2 = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} $$

$$v = \int (3x^2 - 3y^2) dy = 3x^2y - y^3 + \alpha(x)$$

On the other hand

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y } = -6xy  =  -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $$

$$v = \int6xy \;dx = 3x^2y + \beta(y)$$

Comparing those two $v$:

$$3x^2y - y^3 + \alpha(x) = 3x^2y + \beta(y)$$

$$\alpha(x) = \beta(y) + y^3$$

And now I got stucked. What exactly can I say about forms of functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Could you please give me a hand in deriving their true form?

Comment: I can eyeball the underlying compex function $z^3$, which easily leads to $v(x,y)$...

Answer (score 1):

The way I liked to think these partial derivative problems is you take $v_x \cup v_y$

Where $v_x$ and $v_y$ are without the constants.

In your case,
$v_x \cup v_y$
=$(3x^2y-y^3) \cup (3x^2y)$
=$3x^2y-y^3$

Note: My notations are mathematically flawed. It's just what I used to think it like. It's basically what goes in your head and not how you write down.

Also as you did it, if there was $\alpha(x)$ it would appear when you found $v_x$. Since it didn't hence, $\alpha(x)=0$ and the same way $\beta(y)=-y^3$

Also if you're wondering what is $f(x)$, well most likely it's $f(x)=(x+iy)^3$

Comment: $v_x$ is not $3x^2y-y^3$ but $6xy+α'(x)$. $v_y$ is not $3x^2y$, but $3x^2-3y^2$. And I honestly wonder what the rationale is behind the upvote I see here. Cauchy-Riemann conditions are satisfied if and only if $α'(x)=0$, I.e. $α(x)$ is constant. For example, $f(z)=z^3+i$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha(x) = \beta(y) + y^3$ must hold for all $x,y$. Hence, clearly $\alpha(x)=C$ where C is some constant and $\beta(y)= C-y^3$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from:

$$v(x,y)=3x^2y-y^3+α(x)$$

you have found, we have:

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=6xy$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=6xy+α'(x)\;\;.$$

By comparing the last two expressions you deduce:

$$α'(x)=0\quad α(x)=γ_1\;,$$

with $γ_1$ arbitrary real constant.

Therefore, $v(x,y)=3x^2y-y^3+γ_1\;\;.$

You can now find the relevant analytic function:

$$f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+i\,v(x,y)=x^3+3ix^2y-3xy^2-iy^3+γ_2=(x+iy)^3+γ_2=z^3+γ_2\;\;.$$ $γ_2$ is an arbitrary purely imaginary constant.